# Swift How to wait for callback to finish before exiting function?

Tags: swift, callback, wait, apple-watch

The problem I'm having on this request is the first function **syncRequest** always returns nil since the function exits before the (reply, error) comes back to fill out my return dictionary.

Is there a way for it to wait for the callback to return before returning out of my closure?

```
public typealias KKWatchSyncResponse = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

func syncRequest() -> KKWatchSyncResponse? {
    var syncResponseDict : KKWatchSyncResponse?
    createRequest(KKWatchRequest.Sync, parameter: nil) { reply, error in
        if reply == nil || error != nil {
            return
        } else {
            syncResponseDict = KKWatchSyncResponse()
        }
        if let songInfo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(reply!["songInfo"] as NSData) as NSDictionary? {
            syncResponseDict!["songInfo"] = songInfo
        }
        if let albumArtImage = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(reply!["albumArt"] as NSData) as? UIImage {
            syncResponseDict!["albumArtImage"] = albumArtImage
        }
        if let isPlaying = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(reply!["isPlaying"] as NSData) as? Bool {
            syncResponseDict!["isPlaying"] = isPlaying
        }
    }()
    return syncResponseDict
}

    func createRequest(request:KKWatchRequest, parameter: KKWatchAPIRequestParameter?, callback:KKWatchAPICallback) -> KKWatchAPIParentRequest {
       var requestDict : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [KKBOXWatchAppRequestType : request.rawValue]
        if parameter != nil {
        requestDict += parameter! //Combine 2 dictionaries
    }
        return { WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(requestDict){ reply, error in
                callback(reply, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Your help us much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you have `syncRequest()` take a closure that gets called with the results when ready? Change the definition to something like:

```
func syncRequest(callback:(KKWatchSyncResponse?)->Void) { ... }
```

Then at the end of your `createRequest()` call, you could call the callback on `syncResponseDict`, since now it's been populated with your data... `callback(syncResponseDict)`.

EDIT: Here's the solution I had in mind.

```
func syncRequest(callback:(KKWatchSyncResponse?)->Void) {
    createRequest(KKWatchRequest.Sync, parameter: nil) { reply, error in            
        if reply == nil || error != nil {
            callback(nil)
        } else {
            var syncResponseDict : KKWatchSyncResponse? = KKWatchSyncResponse()
            if let songInfo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(reply!["songInfo"] as NSData) as NSDictionary? {
                syncResponseDict!["songInfo"] = songInfo
            }
            if let albumArtImage = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(reply!["albumArt"] as NSData) as? UIImage {
                syncResponseDict!["albumArtImage"] = albumArtImage
            }
            if let isPlaying = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(reply!["isPlaying"] as NSData) as? Bool {
                syncResponseDict!["isPlaying"] = isPlaying
            }
            callback(syncResponseDict)
        }
    }()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is straight forward to implement a locking variable. This is most helpful for unit tests that do some async network loading.

```
func waitingFunction()
{
     //set a lock during your async function
     var locked = true
     RunSome.asyncFunction() { () -> Void in

       //after your sync function remove the lock
       locked = false
     })

     //wait for the async method to complete before advancing
     while(locked){wait()}

     //move on from the lock
     doMoreStuff()
}
func wait()
{
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1))
}
```

Comment: I discourage to use such pattern: Accessing a variable (here `locked`) on different threads without synchronisation is not thread-safe. Here, it happens to work on strongly-ordered CPUs (Intel), but it may fail on ARM. For Unit tests, we have a robust approach in XCTest with expectations which are specifically made for this use case.